# How Can I solve the errors shown in my code

Tags: java, android, qr-code

The Errors Shown include the following:
Cannot resolve symbol 'me' in line 17
Cannot resolve symbol 'ZXingScannerView' in line 19
Cannot resolve method 'setContentView(ZXingScannerView)' in line 40
Cannot resolve method 'setResultHandler(ScanQRActivity)'
Method does not override method from its superclass in line 45
Overriding method should call `super.onRequestPermissionsResult` in line 66
Cannot resolve method 'startCamera()' in line 42

```
package com.gretsa.studentattendance;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class ScanQRActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
private static final int SCAN_QR_REQUEST_CODE = 201;

private ZXingScannerView scannerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanqr);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        startQRScanner();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

private void startQRScanner() {
    scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(scannerView);
    scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    scannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    String qrCodeData = result.getText();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + qrCodeData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Pass the scanned QR code data back to the calling activity
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("qr_code_data", qrCodeData);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (scannerView != null) {
        scannerView.stopCamera();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startQRScanner();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Tried analysing the problem but that didnt help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't added zxing dependencies, try adding these in your gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
   
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
}
```

if it doesn't work, try this library:

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded